# Joining Tables using PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that has been given to me. I want to execute this using a php script, when clicking a button and insert it to another table.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT students.student_id,GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name) FROM
students JOIN teachers ON teachers.subject_teaches =
students.subject_enrolled GROUP BY students.student_id
```

I have a script that shows the content of it and it's working. All I have to do is to insert it to another table. How can I do it?

```
      <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost","root");
            mysql_select_db("join");
            $res=mysql_query("SELECT students.student_id, GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name)FROM students
                              JOIN teachers ON teachers.subject_teaches = students.subject_enrolled
                              GROUP BY students.student_id");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
      ?>
        <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name)'];?></td><br>
        </tr>

       <?php
             }
       ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? We need at least some basic code to work with, otherwise it might not fit into your application

Comment: @Philipp, sir! i have a script that shows it and it's working. All i have to do is to insert it to another table. How can i do it? thanks:

Comment: Can you show the structure of the other table?

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to insert the data of your resultset into the other table, you can simply use this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

querysyntax:

```
INSERT INTO insertTable (columnsOfTable) SELECT columnsToInsert FROM selectTable;
```

In your case:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourtable (columnStudent_id, columnTeachernames) SELECT students.student_id, GROUP_CONCAT(teachers.teacher_name)FROM students
                  JOIN teachers ON teachers.subject_teaches = students.subject_enrolled
                  GROUP BY students.student_id");
```